# Was there ever a black Sith Lord in Star Wars canon or "Legends"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, races

Was there ever a black Sith Lord in Star Wars canon or "Legends"?

To be clear I mean black like:

[image: windu]

Not like:

[image]

Comment: Darth Vader's voice?

Comment: @RogueJedi Funny! When I was a kid I met the dude (David Walker) who played Vader. He was a very nice guy. Also verrrry white.

Comment: How do you define "black" when discussing non-human races?

Comment: @KutuluMike It's a fair question, but I included the photos to clarify that up front. I mostly mean the humans as they were so prevalent anyway, or races close to human. Common sense, basically. Obviously Windu gave us a black Jedi to look up to and I am just wondering if there was also a Sith equivalent, because I think that would be cool. I see a downvote appeared about the same time as your comment. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I think it's a fair question though.

Comment: Should this be rephrased into "black human" instead of just black?

Comment: I tweaked your question to specify "Sith Lord" instead of merely "Sith" because there is a Sith species whose members all have red skin (see my answer). I think this is what you intended and, if so, this should make your question a little clearer. Also, per the Legends tag wiki that tag should be used on this question as well since you specify Legends in the title.

Comment: @Hack-R Prowse, not walker

Comment: to be clear - Mace Windu has brown shaded skin :)
Maul fits the description better than anything.

Comment: I think you mean David Prowse @Hack-R -

Comment: @NKCampbell Oh, you're right! Thanks. I was like 14 so my memory is fuzzy.

Comment: Sometime after KotOR 2, it was revealed that Darth Nihilus had hair that resembled dreadlocks. It is possible that he was a black human.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **no**. The two closest would be:

- [Sora Bulq](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sora_Bulq/Canon), who wasn't human but a [Weequay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Weequay/Legends) humanoid with dark brown skin. He fell to the Dark Side and trained with Count Dooku, before being killed by Quinlan Vos.
- [Kar Vastor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kar_Vastor), a member of the [Korunnai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korun), who wasn't a Sith, but certainly used the Dark Side of the Force.

Both examples are from Legends. Although Sora Bulq does appear in TCW and AOTC, he is only a Jedi in those media.

It is worth noting that the species that Mace Windu and Kar Vastor came from, the Korun, are all force-sensitive, and of those described have all been depicted as black (except for the character Chalk, as Hypnosifl mentions below, whose skin is described ambiguously as 'light-skinned' possibly meaning relative to all the other Korun, as in 'lighter' skinned). Windu had darkness within himself but he channeled it with [Vaapad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII/Legends), the seventh lightsaber form. Both of his contemporary practitioners of Vaapad, Sora Bulq and Depa Billaba, fell to the Dark Side.

Although there is no reference to a Korun Sith, or a Korun dark side practitioner in general, they would be a strong candidate to produce one. Mace Windu describes it thus, from the Mathew Stover novel [Shatterpoint](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shatterpoint_(novel)):

> I don't see Vastor as evil. Not as a truly bad man. Yes, he radiates
>   darkness - but so do all the Korunnai. And the Balawi. His is the
>   darkness of the jungle, not the darkness of the Sith. He does not live
>   for power, to cause pain and dominate all he surveys. He simply
>   *lives*. Fiercely. Naturally. Stripped of the restraints of
>   civilization.
>
> He is less a man than he is an avatar of the jungle itself. Dark power
>   flows into him and out again but it does not seem to touch him. He is
>   a savage purity that I might envy, were I not a Jedi and sworn to the
>   light.
>
> Black is the presence of every color.
>
> He doesn't make the darkness, he only uses it. His inner darkness is a
>   reflection of the darkness of his world; and it darkens the world
>   around him in turn. Internal and external darkness create each other,
>   just as do internal and external light: that is the underlying unity
>   of the Force.

Windu is describing the nature of the Korunnai, his own darkness, and its connection with the Force in general. He saw his [conflict with Kar Vastor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Haruun_Kal/Legends) as his own spiritual fight with his Dark Side, particularly as he had to face his own former Padawan, Depa Billaba, who had fallen to the Dark Side. The Korun therefore would be strong candidates to produce a black Sith, though they have not apparently done so in the available media.

---

N.B.1. There is another species, in the Star Wars Universe, with black people who are Force-users, and those are the [Near-Human](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Near-Human) [Tholothians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tholothian); in Canon there are three Force-users from this species, [Adi Gallia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Adi_Gallia), [Stass Allie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stass_Allie/Legends), and [Katooni](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Katooni) - they were all Jedi, but they are another example of a species with black people who had Force-users amongst them.

N.B.2. Another black Force user, from an unidentified species, was [Tu-Anh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tu-Anh), but she again was a Jedi, not a Sith.

Comment: Great answer. Maybe in the future Disney will allow some more diversity in this good ole boy's club of the Sith order.

Comment: Good answer, but I have to say, isn't it kind of racist that one of the only black men in the entire film series is given the backstory of coming from a race of jungle savages?

Comment: @RogueJedi I was kind of thinking the same thing, but to frame it differently I'd say (a) there were always other black characters in Star Wars, like Lando and (b) if you're going to make a story about humanoids coming from the Jungle it makes anthropological sense that they would have darker hair and eyes. The little cartoon drawing of him didn't event really look "black" but it did say dark hair and brown eyes; he kind of looked South American to me.

Comment: I don't think there's any canon evidence that the Korun are "all black", The Korun character [Chalk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Liane_Trevval) was described in chapter 2 of the novel *Shatterpoint* as "a big light-skinned Korun girl with reddish hair", I suppose it's possible they just meant lighter shade of brown and that the hair was dyed, but the description is also compatible with her resembling a European-looking Earthling.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I read it that way as well, all of the other Korun are depicted as black and in their company she is described as light-skinned, meaning relative to them. The red hair part is less relevant since in their universe there is not necessarily any correlation between dark skin and dark hair that we know of, especially on Korun. I'll edit the post though to take that into account, I shouldn't have said it that strongly.

Comment: @Phyneas - When you say "all the other Korun are depicted as black", how many? I searched my kindle Shatterpoint for the word "skin", the only Korun I saw described as dark-skinned was [Nick Rostu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nick_Rostu), described in ch. 2 as "a slender Korun half Mace's age or less, darker skin" with "startling blue eyes." Also, Chalk was described as "a Korun girl with pale skin and startling red hair" in ch. 18, and described as having a "fair-skinned face" in ch. 3, in the real world both phrases tend to be more strongly associated with Europeans than "light-skinned".

Comment: @Hypnosifl - All of the other Korun who are described/depicted in the SWU. Mace Windu, Kar Vastor, Nick Rostu and Chalk (whom, as I say above, I read as being described as light-skinned compared to the other Korun who are described as dark skinned). There were two other characters, Lesh and Besh, but I couldn't find a description of their skin color. 3 out of 4 are described as dark skinned and the other as either lighter or light skinned. I edited my answer above to make that part clearer as well.

Comment: @Phyneas - When was Kar Vastor's skin color described? I didn't see such a mention when I searched for "skin" in Shatterpoint, and the scene where Mace first sees Vastor in ch. 7, which has two paragraphs on his appearance, doesn't mention his skin color. As for Chalk, like I said she is described as having "pale skin" and being "fair-skinned"--in real life I've heard black people described as "light-skinned" (relative to other black people) but I haven't heard either of those other two descriptions applied to black people, they both are generally used in a less relative way AFAIK.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - it is from 'Luke Skywalker and the Shadows of Mindor' by Matthew Stover - Cronal 'possesses' Kar Vastor and uses him to capture Han and Leia, and while he is doing this he is described as dark-skinned.

Answer (score 12):

There are no black [Sith Lords in canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Lord).

In Legends, there are at least two human Sith Lords with dark skin like Mace Windu's. Both are from the video game [*Star Wars: The Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic), which takes place over 3,000 years before the events of the films.

### [Darth Skotia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Skotia)

[image: Skotia]

### [Darth Arho](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Arho)

[image: Arho]

They are from the [Sith Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Empire_(Post%E2%80%93Great_Hyperspace_War)), which existed before Darth Bane and the Rule of Two. There were many Sith Lords at that time and there are undoubtedly others which are black.

(It is worth noting that, in Legends, there is a [Sith species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_(species)). All members of this species have red skin.)

Comment: I'd wondered if there were any in the KOTOR games (I only played the 2nd out of the 3) but a cursory search didn't pick up on any. Great finds!

Comment: @Phyneas Thanks! It actually took me awhile to find them, even though I'd played the game. I was pretty sure Skotia was black, but I couldn't remember his name so I had a hard time finding even him!

Answer (score 2):

In Star Wars the Canon Universe, no the are not any Black Sith Lords. I don't know about Legends though.

All Canon Sith Lords:

1. Darth Sidious
2. Darth Plagueis
3. Darth Vader
4. Darth Maul
5. Savage Opress (Classified as a Sith)
6. Asajj Ventress (Classified as a Sith)
7. Darth Bane

Comment: Kylo Ren is not a Sith.

Comment: You forgot Dooku(Darth Tyranus).

Comment: Savage Opress and Asajj Ventress were *affiliated* with the Sith, but by the Sith Rule of Two in operation at that time were not Sith *Lords*.

Answer (score -2):

## Darth Vader

[image]

If I am not color blind, Darth Vader is black from top to bottom.

**Note:** Darth Vader is a cyborg and his suit is integral part of his being and identity without which he can't survive.

Comment: Downvoting for not using the correct meaning of “black.”